# Match an id of a sub object to another table

Tags: mongodb

We are converting part of our system from MySQL to MongoDB, and our structure thought is to look something like this (subset):

**Ads**

```
{
    _id: ObjectId(),
    campaign: {
        title: "Some Title",
        budget: 100,
        host: "example.com",
        ads: [{
            // Ad 1 here
        },{
            // Ad 2 here
        },{
            // Ad 3 here
        }]
    }
}
```

So this object would have a `campaign` object containing info such as: title, budget, host, etc. It will also have an `ads` array of objects containing each ad in the campaign.

**Statistics**

```
{
    ad: {
        campaignId: ObjectId(),
        adId: 1
    },
    // Other stuff
}
```

This will contain statistics for each impression/click on an ad found in the `Ads` Collection

Since each ad in the collection above is an array, and has the record in the collection has one `_id`, what is the best way to match statistics to a particular ad within a particular campaign?

Comment: We need more details. What shall the statistics look like? Just a click counter for web banners? A click stream with, source, date and time?

Comment: It will contains lots of stuff such as (but not limited to): screen resolution, ip, browser, browser version, os, os version, geo information from maxmind, browser language, url information, device information, whether it was clicked when viewed etc.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

From the first look, I can't see a reason why to embed the ads into the campaign. Think of massive, global campaigns of somebody like Margaret Astor – you may reach the 16MB document size limit without having the slightest advantage of embedding. I would model that totally different.

The Campaigns should include everything which is not related to a particular ad:

```
{
  _id: new ObjectId(),
  customer: "SomeCustomerReference"
}
```

The individual ads (I assume banners) should look sth like this:

```
{
  campaign: Ref("SomeCampaignId"),
  someInfo: "Awesome product from Acme!"
  ...
}
```

So, we have cleaned this up. Now, to the statistics. First of all, you may add a counter to the above adds and use the [$inc operator](http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/operator/update/inc/) on this counter. However, this isn't very granular. So I would use a third collection for each impression

```
{
  _id: ObjectId(),
  ad: Ref("Ad"),
  impression: new ISODate(),
  location: "http://awesome.cool/",
}
```

Now, all you have to do when the ad was clicked is to update the impression:

```
db.impressions.update(
  { _id: "SomeIdDerivedFromReferralCode" },
  { $set: { clicked: new ISODate() } }
)
```

Last but not least, you can use the [aggregation framework](http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/core/aggregation/) and some other means to get a lot of information from that simple structure. A simple example is to count the clicked impressions of ad "foo":

```
db.impressions.find({ ad:"foo", clicked:{ $exists: true } } ).count()
```

You can identify at which time of day and which day of week the most/the least clicks happened, how many ads were clicked on Dec 24th last year and whatnot.

Since we haven't used embedded documents or arrays, this model scales out very well. No chance to touch the 16MB document size limit, no frequent document migrations because of members added to large arrays.

Comment: Also, the ads are both banners and text. In the future we might support more, such as videos or local business listings, but as of now it is **text ads** and **banner ads**